# jQuery item fly in an U shape

Tags: jquery, image

Is there a way to make an element to fly in a upside down U shape through the screen and rotate continuously?
I'm working on a script and I need to create this effect: an image appears from the bottom left corner of the screen, go 50% of the screen's height and fall through the right corner of the screen. I need to do this every 1 minute, but I can do this with setInterval.

What I've done:

```
var currWidth = $(window).width();
console.log(currWidth);

var startPos = -100;
var endPos = (currWidth + 100) + (startPos / 2);
console.log(endPos);
setInterval(
function(){
$('.bouquet').animate({left: endPos}, 3000);

var offset = $(e.target).offset();
    $('.bouquet').animate({'top':offset.top},600);
}, 10000
);
```

But it goes from the left of the screen to the right, so it does not work OK.

Comment: did you try to do it your self? show us what did you achieve

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like a really annoying effect to me.

Comment: I know, but one of my clients asked me to do this... So I need to do this... To be honest, I don't like it neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this won't be easy. You'll need to do two animations at once, like

```
//first half of the motion
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.bouquet').animate({left: endPos/2}, 3000,'<easing>');
},0);

setTimeout($('.bouquet').animate({top:offset.top}, 3000,'<easing>',function(){
    //on complete: other half of the motion
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.bouquet').animate({left: endPos}, 3000,'<easing>');
    },0);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.bouquet').animate({top:offset.top}, 3000,'<easing>'
    }),0)
}),0)
```

with an easing function that provides a quadratic function for the left-right motion and a linear one for the up-down motion. Else it would just be a line...but i'm not sure about which easings these are, may someone add that. the two `setTimeout` functions should not block, and thus both animations should happen at the same time

[EDIT] ...okay, i just tried it and it seems impossible to do multiple animations on one object at the same time. but i came up with another possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/7AHLb/1

it's not perfect yet, but if you play a bit with it, it might help you.

Comment: @Rawrrr1337 you'll need to make some changes to the easing functions, maybe you find an plugin to give you the right easings...